# How to tell Windows to fall back to "automatic DNS server discovery" while still preferring a specific fixed one?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, dns, dhcp

So I have this weird situation that on my laptop running Windows 10 (Home) I...

- need to use Windows' feature to fetch a DNS server automatically (which uses the DHCP suggested DNS?) on certain networks
- while I still want to use `1.1.1.1` and / or `1.0.0.1` as my "regular" DNS servers if available.

Now you can only tell Windows using the normal IPv4 properties that you either want the auto-fetch *or* you can specify two fixed IP adresses, but as I don't know the dynamic ones in advance so I can't specify the automatic one as secondary to `1.1.1.1`.

**So are there any ways to tell Windows to fall-back to the DHCP provided DNS server if the static ones are not reachable?**

Also in theory I could switch these every time I connect to networks that require that, but that's always a PITA to remember and then do the neccessary changes every time before connecting to and after disconnecting from these networks.

More background: The network forcing me to use the DHCP provided DNS is a public network which won't display me the captive portal required to gain internet access if I have `1.1.1.1` and `1.0.0.1` configured as static DNS servers.

Comment: 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 both resolves as long as you have internet access... so you shouldn't need to change DNS entry... unless you have very specific need to get the DHCP-advertised DNS server?

Comment: @Darius I want to / need to connect to a specific network that won't show me the captive portal if 1.1.1.1 / 1.0.0.1 are specificed but only if the DHCP provided DNS is used. (ie I had 1.1.1.1 / 1.0.0.1 specified and it only started working once I made Windows switch to the DHCP provided server)